# IIS needs to be restarted every morning

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

In one of my Application and DB Server , SSIS package runs at night. Every morning i need to reset IIS to work the Application Fast and smoothly. One day i tried to SKIP the SSIS Package and next day i hvnt Done the IIS reset.

What could be the problem. Is there any alternate Solution for IIS reset.

How can i schedule and make sure the IIS is RESTARTED through Batch File / s.

Application is developed in .NET and DB is SQL latest version. The application is hostes on cloud server.

Your prompt reply will be helpful for me.

Comment: Your question is worded very poorly. Try to rephrase it, and describe your problem more in-depth. Also, read the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq)

Answer (score 1):

> What could be the problem.

Defective hardware, broken software, too small server, simple like that.

> How can i schedule and make sure the IIS is RESTARTED through Batch File / s.

- Create batch file to restart IIS with Net Stop and net Start
- Schedule batch file using scheduling mechanism.
- Look for a job outside IT as a fix like that may get you fired - it is if anything only a workaround.

> Application is developed in .NET and DB is SQL latest version.

Properly fully patched, also with the regular CU, that is regularly eleased (and means cumulative update)? And you talk of SQL Servr 2012, right? THAT is the latest release.

> The application is hostes on cloud server

That translates to me: The application runs on an underpowered system with not enough RAM and simply overloads the server, which is most likely pathetic on the ONE important item for database servers - disc IOPS budget, which is particularly THE performance limitator and also THE bottleneck on cloud machines.

Mostly because I Have rarely seen cloud servers that are worth being mentioned when we talk of database servers. If anything, the move to the cloud sort of psuhes everyont to way too small systems.

Have you tried finding out what is wrong? Memory? Who / what uses it? The main way to fix issues like that is to start behaving like a pro and do an analysis of WHAT is going wrong.